# Group by multiple items in list then sum and average c#

Tags: c#, linq, list, group-by

I need to perform quite a complicated query and having difficulty doing it. what I have is a list of objects called LiquidityBuilder:

```
public class LiquidityBuilder
{
    private string _lp;
    private string _timezone;
    private int _size;
    private bool _ask;

    public string LP
    {
        get { return _lp; }
    }

    public int Size
    {
        get { return _size; }
    }

    public string Timezone
    {
        get { return _timezone; }
    }

    public bool Ask
    {
        get { return _ask; }
    }

    public LiquidityBuilder(string lp, string timezone, int size, bool ask)
    {
        _lp = lp;
        _timezone = timezone;
        _size = size;
        _ask = ask;
    }
}
```

The data will look something like this:

```
LP      Timezone      Size     Ask
GS       LDN        1000000  True
GS       LDN        3000000  True
GS       TOR        2000000  True
JPM      TOR        1000000  False
CS       ASIA       1000000  True
JPM      TOR        1000000  False
CITI     TOR        2000000  False
```

I'm first trying to group by the "LP" then by "Timezone" then by "Ask" then sum the sizes. So example,

```
GS     (Ask)
LDN: 4000000
TOR: 2000000
```

This is what I have:

```
var groupedLiquidityList = liquidtyTimezoneData
    .GroupBy(u => u.LP && u.Timezone && u.Ask)
    .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

now I can't group by string's what would also be the most efficient way to do this because performance matters for the application I'm developing..Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain the logic of average more clearly? I mean how you are expecting it to be.

Comment: Actually let's just forget about the average for now, because I think I'll have to do a separate grouping by the LP and "Ask" then I can average their sizes once I can get the sum for each timezone. Let's jsut focus on the summing and grouping. Thanks @RahulSingh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting the sum, as per your comment you can try this:-

```
var result = liquidtyTimezoneData.GroupBy(x => new { x.LP, x.Timezone, x.Ask })
                                 .Select(x => new
                                             {
                                                 LP = x.Key.LP,
                                                 Timezone = x.Key.Timezone,
                                                 Ask = x.Key.Ask,
                                                 Sum = x.Sum(z => z.Size)
                                              });
```

Then simply iterate it with a `foreach` loop:-

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
   Console.WriteLine("LP: {0}, Timezone: {1}, Ask : {2}, Sum : {3}",item.LP,item.Timezone,item.Ask,item.Sum);
}
```

I am getting following output:-

[image]

Comment: how are you iterating over result? @Rahul Singh

Comment: I get an exception on the second iteration with this: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. @Rahul Singh

Comment: @kknaguib - The maximum value of an integer must have exceeded, try using `long` instead of `int` for `Size` property.

Comment: Thanks Rahul! @Rahul Singh

Comment: Rahul, I have another quick question, I'm trying to get the count as well now for the same combination of LP,Timezone and Ask. I've tried Count = x.Count(f => f.LP) but it says you can't implicitly convert type bool to string. @Rahul Singh

Comment: @kknaguib - Hey! You need to just invoke `x.Count()` that will do, in case of `Sum` we passed a parameter because we wanted the sum of  `Size`, but for count we need to just count the no. of items.